# When upgrading to .NET 6, Web Project throws runtime exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

Using an existing .NET 5 MVC Web App, I attempted to upgrade to .NET 6, but encountered this error.  I am also using IIS for Windows Authentication--now setup in .NET 6 as "profiles" under Properties -> Debug -> hyperlink (Open debug launch profiles UI).  I also included the newer "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Nuget package (and associated code) to handle the newer Windows Authentication library.

When the web app launches, I get the following error:

> **An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**
>
> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs'
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List assemblies)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPartExtensions+<>c.b__0_0(CompilationLibrary library)
> System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext()
>
> ...
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

This does NOT go away if I add the package listed:  **System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to **remove** at least 1 **Nuget package**:

1. **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** -- I removed this one second, but it started working after I did.
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting -- I removed this one first, but this alone did not fix it.  I don't know if this "also" needed to be removed.  I assume not, but I'm including, just in case.  Removing it did not hurt anything.

Edit:  As a **WARNING**, this will lose the abilities given by Razor.RuntimeCompilation.  However, there appears to be a code incompatibility with, I believe, IIS and Razor in .NET 6.

[image: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc>Razor.RuntimeCompilation]

Comment: This did help me to get similar issue solved (I were getting `Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Build'`). But instead of removing that package, I've simply commented out .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation in my Startup.cs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, however, I just experienced this issue right after I changed the Development Web Server from `IISExpress` to `IIS` in a .NET6 project.

In order to fix it, I just had to install the [System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs) NuGet Package.

This allowed me to keep the *Razor Runtime Compilation* feature enabled, which I didn't want to lose.

I hope this helps other people having this same issue. For further info about this topic, read [this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/cannot-find-compilation-library-system-security-cryptography-pkcs-fix/) on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error only when running application (piranha cms) inside docker container.
I had to remove razor runtime compilation to make it work.

```
// comment out or delete this line
// options.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation = true;
```